# Error 1001 Ray ID: 2857dcb38d972ee7

Tags: discussion, bug, cloudflare

Today while browsing i found error on SO.

[image]

DNS resolution error

Is this normal? Apologies if it makes no sense to you guys.

**Update:** After a min or two i refreshed the page and it is loading fine. I don't think there is any ISP issue.

Comment: I also get this error many times, may be some network issue. Refreshing the page might help.

Comment: I just checked now and found link is working fine.

Comment: Never seen that.  Hit your ISP, not SO :)

Comment: This could be an issue between CloudFlare and your ISP.

Comment: Cloudflare errors are common for users from India in the past several months.  The outage typically doesn't last more than an hour, give or take.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Why would it be an issue between CloudFlare and *the OP's* ISP? The message looks like an issue between CloudFlare and StackOverflow.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think he mean the end point where all traffic of that ISP comes from

Comment: I encountered this and it's been hours. I can reach meta.stackoverflow.com but not stackoverflow.com